# Redux Alternative

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs, redux

I have recently started learning React and I quickly encountered the problem of a bloated parent component full of functions and state. At first I looked at Flux and then I looked at Redux but both seemed like really overbearing solutions.

I am wondering why something like this is not done:

```js
//EventPropagator.js
let EventPropagator = {
    registerListener(listenerObject){
        if (this.listeners == null)
            this.listeners = []
        this.listeners.push(listenerObject)
    },
    fireEvent(eventObject){
        let listenerList = this.listeners.filter(function(listener){
            return listener.eventType === eventObject.eventType
        })
        listenerList.forEach((listener) => {
            listener.callback(eventObject.payload)
        })
    }
}
export default EventPropagator
```

**To use:** components simply `registerListener` and `fireEvent`:

```js
//main.js
import EventPropagator from './events/EventPropagator'

EventPropagator.registerListener({
    "eventType": "carry_coconut",
    "callback": (payload) => {
        // actually carry coconut
        this.setState({"swallow_type": payload.swallow})
        console.log(payload)
    }
})
EventPropagator.fireEvent({
    "eventType": "carry_coconut",
    "payload": { "swallow": "african" }
})
```

This would allow a lot of decoupling and state could easily be passed around with this sort of event. What are the downsides to this approach?

Comment: Jumpstate looks good https://github.com/jumpsuit/jumpstate.

Comment: This approach would solve the issue of cross-component communication, but you would still need to manage each components data locally, in `state`. Other than the actions and reducers, redux also helps, so you don't have to think about local state, and how to keep it in sync among (probably many) components.

Comment: you can try https://rootzjs.org/

Answer (score 5):

You should try [mobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx)

[mobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) is a state management library which took the advantage of [decorators](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.48h6tpg9z) and succeeded in removing unwanted code. For example, there is no concept of `reducers` in mobx.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks interesting but there's still a much higher learning curve than the above and it doesn't look to me as though you gain much... Thanks for the link though, I will look at it in more detail!

Answer (score 2):

There is `Reactn` based in hooks.
It is orders of magnitude easier to use, compared to Redux. 
Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactn and read [Stover's blog](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZxrjD3pTiAhWMJ7kGHcHkB68QFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fswlh%2Fno-boilerplate-global-state-management-in-react-907589d9554f&usg=AOvVaw1Xxr0siihLlxSFfZuY7cUq).

Comment: Finally I have to deal with global state. Because I have already read Charles Stover article on his ReactN lib, I tried it this morning, and it worked for as expected. In my app, I need information of login user which will be shared to all modules/forms. ReactN solves this. Thanks to Stover who provides support for not only function components that use hooks but also class based ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take advantage of all the Redux benefits, use Redux.

If you only want to keep a var on sync between React components, use Duix.

I'm the Duix's creator. I've been using it for 1 year, and finally, I released it a few hours ago. Check the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/duix

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Hookstate](https://hookstate.js.org/). It gives the same simplest API for [local](https://hookstate.js.org/docs/local-state), [lifted](https://hookstate.js.org/docs/nested-state), and [global](https://hookstate.js.org/docs/global-state) states. First class typescript. DevTools support. Extendable with plugins. Comprehensive documentation. It has got state usage tracking feature and smart re-rendering of only deeply nested affected components. This makes it the fastest state management solution for [large frequently changing states](https://hookstate.js.org/docs/performance-frequent-updates). Disclaimer: I am maintainer of the project.

Comment: I think this is the best alternative to Redux, the API looks simple and intuitive. I have to decide between hookstate and pullstate ( another similar state management package) for my upcoming project. I like yours better because of the logging.development features.

Comment: thanks, I believe pullstate does not have many features of hookstate, not mentioning performance and lib size.

Comment: I just researched more. Quick question, what do you think of https://easy-peasy.now.sh/ ? Has got great reviews.

Comment: As far as I can see it uses selector functions in useStoreState. This is a bit more boilerplate than hookstate, and it is slower: O(n) scalability VS O(1) offered by Hookstate (read more here: https://hookstate.js.org/docs/scoped-state#it-is-unique)

Answer (score 0):

What is needed is an event driven system so a child component can speak to its sibling but this does not mean that data should be passed as the events payload. That would lead to a system of no governance and a nightmare for a project where multiple developers are working on it.

So long as you follow the flux-like architecture pattern (google it) then you actually can do this successfully with just javascript and Javascript objects to hold the data along with the event system.

Data should be treated as being one of three different states. It's either

1. original data pulled from the server
2. transformed data (transformed from the original)
3. Store data. That which acts as the model which the UI is bound to

If you write a javascript library to handle the movement of data between the three states and handle the transforms you can use the event system to to fire a "store changed" event that components can listen to and self-rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Redux is a continuation of React's declarative programming Style. A simple way of mapping your application logic to components is to use something like [Backbone.React.Component](https://github.com/magalhas/backbone-react-component) but using redux, will let you use all the tooling & middle-ware. Also have indefinite transitions in your apps makes debugging a lot easier. Now, I agree that you need a lot of wiring & boilerplate to get anyway.

If you want to use redux, you could look at something like [redux-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto)

> Redux-auto: Redux made easy (with a plug and play approach)
>
> Removing the boilerplate code in setting up a store & actions. why? This utility to allow you to get up and running with Rudux in a fraction of the time!

You can see now a [redux-auto: helloworld project](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto/tree/master/example)

Comment: Maybe add a disclaimer that it's your project.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/deepakpatil84/pure-data
Note: i am the author of this

Answer (score 0):

Using your EventPropagator solves the problem of communication, but does not handle data integrity. For example, if there are more than 2 components listening to same event, and using that event's payload to update their own states. The more components listen to same events, the more complex it is to make sure that all those components have same data in their own states.

Secondly, Flux/Redux provides uni-directional data flow. A simple example could be about 2 components A & B, consuming same data X from external source (API or storage). User can interact with either of them to get latest X data. Now if user asks B to update X, we have 2 solutions with your EventPropagator:

1. B will update X itself, and fire an event to inform A about the update to let A re-rendered. Same goes for A if user asks A to update X. This is bi-directional data flow.
2. B will fire an event to A asking to update X, and await A to fire an event back to get updated X. If user asks A to update, **A will do it itself and inform B**. This is uni-directional data flow.

Once your number of components goes large and communication is not limited between only A & B, you might need to stick with only one of those 2 above solution to avoid your app's logic going wild. Flux/Redux chooses the second, and we are happy with that.

If you really don't think you need another library for data control, you should look at [the newest feature of React: Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). It provides most essential features that a data control library can have, and it's React only. Noted that you have to update your project's React version to 16.3 to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Another modest multi-store alternative is [react-scopes](https://github.com/rscopes/react-scopes)

Here are some features:

- Simple decorators syntax,
- Allow defining independent store logic directly in Components
- Easily connect stores through the Components tree
- Allow templating complex / async data process
- SSR with async data
- etc

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [Reducs](https://github.com/mobily-enterprises/reducs). It's only 25 lines of code, it doesn't require boilerplate, and... did I mention that it's only 25 lines of code?
I am using it for a big project, and it's holding up very well.  There is a [live example that uses lit-html and Reducs](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lacy-ornament).

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues, with lot of switch, case, etc... 
I create for myself something as alternative, you could take a look:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/micro-reducers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [JetState](https://github.com/mnasyrov/jetstate) for state management with RxJS. I wrote this for my Angular projects and later adapted it for using with React's hooks.

Answer (score 0):

[PullState](https://github.com/lostpebble/pullstate) I really want this underdog to shine. Tried other similar ones which promised quick and no-boilerplate-ness, none came close to the ease of use of PullState. I just read the first page of the  documentation and implemented it in one of my pages and it just worked. It is easy to understand if you already using functional components in react.

Comment: Hookstate (http://hookstate.js.org/) not only comes close, it goes beyond in API simplicity, feature set and performance. Disclaimer: I am maintainer of the project.